# System of ODEs obtained by using the method of characteristics for $u_x + 2u_t - 4u = e^{x+t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a question which requires me to use the method of characteristics in order to solve the PDE $u_x + 2u_t - 4u = e^{x+t}$.

This results in the system of ODE's $\frac{dx}{dr} = 1 , \frac{dt}{dr} = 2 , \frac{du}{dr} = 4u + e^{x+t} $

The solutions to the first two equations are $x = r + c_1$ and $t = 2r + c_2$ respectively however when solving the third equation I get $u = c_4e^{4r} - e^{3r + c1 + c2}$ and according to my prof the solution to this equation is supposed to be  $u = c_3e^{4r} + e^{4r + c1 + c2}(1-e^{-r})$ and I'm not sure how that got that.

Answer (score 0):

on the characteristic you have $x = r+c_1, t = 2r+c_2$ and $$\frac{du}{dr} -4u =e^{x+t} = e^{3r+c_1 + c_2}\to \frac{d}{dr}\left(ue^{-4r}\right)=e^{-r+c_1+c_2}$$ which on integration gives you $$ue^{-4r}= c_3-e^{-r_1 + c_1 + c_2}\to u = c_3e^{4r}-e^{3r+c_1+c_2} $$

your solution and the profs solution are the same. the reason is if you identify $$c_4 = c_3 +e^{c_1+c_2}$$ then you can see that both are equal.

Comment: Im just curious as to how he got that in the first place, I used what you showed with the integrating factor to get that answer. It would seem that I can get his solution by integrating the right hand side from 0 to r instead of indefinitely, however I've never done this before to solve an ODE and I was wondering if there was a reason for doing it.

Comment: @user2253455, your prof is finding a particular solution because you are going to be adding the hfs solution anyway. so you can make the initial value anything you want. here he/she made the initial value zero at $r = 0$

Comment: that makes a bit more sense. thanks

Answer (score 0):

With free Maxima CAS and my package "diffops.mac":

(%i1)   load(diffops);

(%o1)   "C:/Users/aleksas/maxima/diffops.mac"

(%i2)   eq:'diff(u,x)+2*'diff(u,t)-4*u=exp(x+t)$

(%i3)   solveLpde(eq,u,[x,t]);

(%o3)   %e^(2*t)*f1(2*x-t)-%e^(x+t)

Then general solution of equation $u_x+2u_t-4u=e^{x+t}\;$   is
$$u=e^{2t}f(2x-t)-e^{x+t}$$

Some details:

- $u=e^{2t}f(2x-t)\;$ is general solution of homogeneus equation $u_x+2u_t-4u=0$
- $u=-e^{x+t}\;$ is particular solution of  $u_x+2u_t-4u=e^{x+t}\;$